# What is the correct way to capitalise the name 'XBOX'?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, xbox

I've always written 'Xbox' myself, but saw 'xBox' today and realised I would like some clarification on the right way to write it.

In fact, is it even one word? Is it 'X Box'?

Is there a correct way at all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[It's Xbox](https://www.xbox.com/). Can't get more official than the official website.

Comment: Thanks. Even though everybody hated my question...

Comment: @C.R.Yasuo No one 'hated' your question. Disagreeing doesn't equate to hatred which is an extremely strong emotion. They downvoted you most likely because it's something that can be very easily researched (i.e., official website).

Comment: @deutschZuid You're right. I spoke too quickly and didn't think. Right now, I don't even know why I didn't think of just looking on the official website when I asked this question. Sorry.